# "Es gibt zwei Supermärkte in meiner Stadt." case of Stadt

Tags: grammatical-case

I was thinking about the sentence

> Es gibt zwei Supermärkte in meiner Stadt.

and I was stuck to whether Stadt would be dative or genitive.

I know meiner is the possessive adjective in this situation but I thought as the "Stadt" belongs to me, this would be the genitive case i.e. the "Supermärkte" belongs to "Stadt".

Is it genitive or dative?

And to add, if it is genitive (and I am right) why would you need the preposition "in" i.e. why not just write:

> Es gibt zwei Supermärkte meiner Stadt.

Comment: "Es gibt zwei Supermärkte in ..." in wem oder in was? -> dative. For genitive, it would have to read e.g., "Die zwei Supermärkte meiner Stadt haben schon geschlossen." Your example for genitive is not idiomatic. You will be understood, but it sounds more like the city owns the supermarkets, as opposed to the supermarkets being in the city.

Comment: @Robert Die Frage nach dem Ort heißt _Wo?_

Answer (score 6):

"In meiner Stadt" is an adverbial telling the *place*.

The preposition *in* governs dative or accusative, never genitive. Because it's about place and not about direction, dative is the only option.

"Es gibt zwei Supermärkte meiner Stadt" is not ungrammatical, but highly unusual.

Comment: This would also indicate, that the city owns them.

Answer (score 2):

Dativ wenn man sagt, Es gibt zwei Supermärkte in meiner Stadt.

Genetiv: Diese zwei Märkte meiner Stadt sind schön

Stadt hat den Artikel "die" so in Genetiv wird "der"